# analytic approximations of the min and max operators

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, convex-optimization, approximation-theory, norms

### Question:

What is the state of the art on analytic approximations of $\min$ and $\max$? My hunch is that numerical analysts probably have a better solution than the one I propose here.

For any $\epsilon$, I'd like analytic approximations $f$ that

1. Are accurate to within $\epsilon$, in the sense that
   $$|f(V)-\max(V)|<\epsilon$$
   for any vector $V$ in $[-1000,1000]^{100}$, and
2. Minimize the expected [relative error](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativeError.html):

$$E\left[\left|\frac{f(V)-\max(V)}{\max(V)}\right|\right]$$
where $V$ is a random vector uniformly distributed in $[-1000,1000]^{100}$.

### Motivation:

Within the context of optimisation, differentiable approximations of the min and max operators are very useful. In particular I am looking for $f_N,g_N \in C^\infty$:

\begin{equation}
f_N: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
g_N: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{equation}

where $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n \forall \epsilon >0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$:

\begin{equation}
\forall m > N, \max(\lvert f_m(x)-\max(x) \rvert,\lvert g_m(x)-\min(x) \rvert) < \epsilon
\end{equation}

I found a few proposed solutions to a [related question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35191/a-differentiable-approximation-to-the-minimum-function) but when I tested these methods I found that none of them were numerically stable with respect to the relative error  $\frac{\lvert \delta x \rvert}{\lvert x \rvert}$. Without much loss of generality, I shall focus on approximations of the max operator.

In total, I analysed three different analytic approximations to the max operator $\forall X \in \mathbb{R}^n, \forall N \in \mathbb{N}$:

1. The [generalised mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean):

\begin{equation}
 GM(X,N)= \big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^N\big)^{\frac{1}{N}} \tag{1}
\end{equation}

2. Exponential generalised mean:

\begin{equation}
 EM(X,N)= \frac{1}{N} \cdot \log \big(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n e^{N \cdot x_i}\big) \tag{2}
\end{equation}

3. The [smooth max](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_maximum):

\begin{equation}
 SM(X,N)= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \cdot e^{N \cdot x_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^n e^{N \cdot x_i}} \tag{3}
\end{equation}

and found that all of these methods were vulnerable to overflow errors. In fact, I created an [IJulia notebook](https://github.com/AidanRocke/analytic_min-max_operators/blob/master/analytic_max_operator.ipynb) where I analysed each method.

### My proposed method:

This motivated me to come up with my own solution inspired by the properties of the [infinity norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions) where I first rescale the vectors so they have zero mean and unit variance:

\begin{equation}
AM(\hat{X},N) = \sigma_X \cdot \big(\frac{1}{N} \log \big(\sum_{i=1}^n e^{N\cdot \hat{x_i}} \big)\big) + \mu_{X} \tag{4a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hat{X} = \frac{X - 1_n\cdot \mu_X}{\sigma_X} \tag{4b}
\end{equation}

whose partial derivative with respect to $\hat{x_i}$ is simply the softmax:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \hat{x_i}} AM(\hat{X},N) = \frac{e^{N \cdot \hat{x_i}}}{\sum_{i=1}^n e^{N\cdot \hat{x_i}}} \tag{5}
\end{equation}

This may be be used to approximate both the min and max operators on $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the Julia programming language:

```
using Statistics

function analytic_min_max(X::Array{Float64, 1},N::Int64,case::Int64)

    """
        An analytic approximation to the min and max operators

        Inputs: 
            X: a vector from R^n where n is unknown

            N: an integer such that the approximation of max(X) 
               improves with increasing N.

            case: If case == 1 apply analytic_min(), otherwise 
                  apply analytic_max() if case == 2

        Output: 

            An approximation to min(X) if case == 1, and max(X) if 
            case == 2
    """

    if (case != 1)*(case != 2)

        return print("Error: case isn't well defined")

    else

        ## q is the degree of the approximation: 
        q = N*(-1)^case

        mu, sigma = mean(X), std(X)

        ## standardise the vector so it has zero mean and unit variance:
        Z_score = (X.-mu)./sigma

        exp_sum = sum(exp.(-Z_score*q))

        log_ = log(exp_sum)/q

        return (log_*sigma)+mu

    end

end
```

and as expected it passed the numerical stability test that I defined:

```
function numerical_stability(method,type::Int64)

    """
        A simple test for numerical stability with respect to the relative error. 

        Input: 

            method: the approximation used

            type: 1 for min() and 2 for max()

        Output: 

            Check that the average relative error is less than 10%.  

    """

    ## test will be run 100 times 
    relative_errors = zeros(100)

    for i = 1:100

        ## a vector sampled uniformly from [-1000,1000]^100
        X = (2*rand(100).-1.0)*1000

        ## the test for min operators
        if type == 1

            min_ = minimum(X)

            relative_errors[i] = abs(min_-method(X,i))/abs(min_)

        ## the test for max operators
        else 

            max_ = maximum(X)

            relative_errors[i] = abs(max_-method(X,i))/abs(max_)

        end

    end

    return mean(relative_errors) < 0.1

end
```

### References:

1. Wikipedia contributors. Smooth maximum. Wikipedia, The Free Encyclopedia. March 25, 2019, 21:07 UTC. Available at: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Smooth_maximum&oldid=889462421. Accessed February 12, 2020.
2. alwayscurious (https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/194748/alwayscurious), What is the reasoning behind standardization (dividing by standard deviation)?, URL (version: 2019-03-18): https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/398116
3. Sergey Ioffe & Christian Szegedy. Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training by Reducing Internal Covariate Shift. 2015.
4. J. Cook. Basic properties of the soft maximum. Working Paper Series 70, UT MD Anderson Cancer
   Center Department of Biostatistics, 2011. https://www.johndcook.com/soft_maximum.pdf
5. M. Lange, D. Zühlke, O. Holz, and T. Villmann, "Applications of lp-norms and their smooth approximations for gradient based learning vector quantization," in Proc. ESANN, Apr. 2014, pp. 271-276.
6. Aidan Rocke. analytic_min-max_operators(2020).GitHub repository, https://github.com/AidanRocke/analytic_min-max_operators

Comment: At least from the deep learning side, I think the practice is to avoid overflow concerns by making sure the input to the loss has been passed through a sigmoid function, or some other order-preserving normalization.

Comment: What does rand(100) mean? Is that 100 random numbers uniformly distributed between 0 and 1?

Comment: @MattF. That is correct.

Comment: I've edited to reflect that clarification; you're welcome to edit further or revert. It would also help to clarify: are you looking for functions $f$ and $g$ that are analytic (as in the title of the post) or merely differentiable?

Comment: @MattF. I appreciate your edit and I think I will add comments to the code as well. And yes, I am looking for functions that are ideally analytic so I like the way you framed the question.

Comment: Your link to the J Cook paper seems to be dead

Comment: @kodlu Thank you for pointing this out. It should work now.